# How do you code/wire-up a cancel-button for a panel

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using the new Firefox Add-on SDK that uses `common.js`.

I have a panel what contain some HTML5. I want to have a cancel button; in which when pressed, it closes down the panel. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a content script that sends a message back to the extension when the cancel button is clicked. The extension can then close the panel. Something along these lines:

```js
var data = require("self").data;
var panel = require("panel").Panel({
  contentURL: data.url("panel.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("panel.js"),
  onMessage: function(message)
  {
    if (message == "close")
      panel.hide();
  }
});

panel.show();
```

With `panel.js` containing code like:

```js
var cancelBtn = document.getElementById("cancel");
cancelBtn.addEventListener("click", function()
{
  self.postMessage("close");
}, false);
```

Comment: Here is a note to FireFox addon newbies: In testing this, do not use an alert() in onMessage to test.